# Batch-Matrix multiplication in Pytorch - Confused with the handling of the output's dimension

Tags: python, vectorization, pytorch, batch-processing, matrix-multiplication

I got two arrays :

```
A
B
```

Array `A` contains a batch of RGB images, with shape:

```
[batch, Width, Height, 3]
```

whereas Array `B` contains coefficients needed for a "transformation-like" operation on images, with shape:

```
[batch, 4, 4, 3]
```

To put it simply, the operation for a single image is a multiplication that outputs an environment map (`normalMap * Coefficients`).

The output I want should hold shape:

```
[batch, Width, Height, 3]
```

I tried using `torch.bmm` but failed. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I do not understand the dimensions of the matrix multiplication?
Does the multiplication need to work on the channels axis?
Maybe check out `torch.nn.functional.conv2d`?

Comment: @Danos I want for each image in the batch from tensor A to be multiplicated with the   4*4 matrix from tensor B, respectively on the channel axis yes.

Comment: According to the documentation of [torch.bmm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.bmm), the matrix dimensions must agree (i.e. Height is equal to 4 if it's A*B).
If this is not the case, it makes sense the operation failed.
If you want element-wise multiplication, check out [torch.mul](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.bmm) which in this case I think you need to make sure the B is broadcastable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to calculate that PyTorch works with

```
BxCxHxW : number of mini-batches, channels, height, width
```

format, and also use [`matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=matmul#torch.matmul), since [`bmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=bmm#torch.bmm) works with tensors or ndim/dim/rank =3.

I know you may find this online, but for any case:

```
batch1 = torch.randn(10, 3, 20, 10)
batch2 = torch.randn(10, 3, 10, 30)
res = torch.matmul(batch1, batch2)
res.size() # torch.Size([10, 3, 20, 30])
```